# Free Graphics for a simple game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, graphics, children

I'm creating a game for the android phone atm. It is a very simple game. I have nearly done all my programming. I'm starting to put together some graphics for the game.

The game is about a cat, and giving the cat food etc to keep it happy. I would much appreciate it if the community could point me towards sites which give some simple graphics for games free(if there is any?).

The game is for children, so I would the cat to be colorful. I think I would like to use a cartoon image rather than a real image of a cat. Do you think this is suitable? I'm open to any suggestions!

Much thanks!
Mike

P.S I am creating the game in flash using Actionscript.

Comment: If the cat needs to be animated, I think you will have to end up hiring an artist. Also, if the cat is the main character and you want some uniqueness in your game, it probably pays to have a professional artist do it.

Comment: I see. I don't need to animate the character, just change some color properties. Thankyou, I will keep your suggestion in mind. Out of curiosity where would I look if I need some professional artist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use www.openclipart.org

Search for "cartoon cat" - there are some nice ones there

You will want to make sure your images and not only free, but can be used for commercial use.  The ones on that site generally are, unless stated (but those seem to be rare).

Most of the images on that site are SVG.  I tend to use Inkscape (free software) to open those images and edit them.  A bonus is they are vector graphics (which SVG's are), so you can change the size of them without degrading quality.   You can then export the image as a PNG, which will retain the transparency that you will need in your game

Comment: Nice! Thanks. I will check it out (down for maintenance atm).